# Python import problem in command line mode

Tags: python, importerror

I have the following code structure running perfectly fine in my IDE(Aptana Studio):

```
/ProjectName/
    /lib
    /src
        /Module1
        /Module2
        /Module3
         __init__.py
         pyClass.py         ##Python Class
        /main
         main.py
```

main.py :

```
import Module3.pyClass as pc

myClass=pc.pyClass()
```

but when I try to run it from command line , import error !

```
importError: No module named Module3.pyClass
```

I am running from the /main directory. Is it because it doesn't know where to find Module3 to import?How should i tell where it should look for Module3 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add the following lines in your main.py before the import and give us the output : `import sys`, `print sys.path`. If you don't find /path/to/ProjectName/src/ in your Python path, you need to add it. You also need to add a __init__.py file in src.

Comment: Make sure that PYTHONPATH environment variable / sys.path Python variable contain /ProjectName/src/ . You might want to set PYTHIONPATH to whatever Aptana is setting it to.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to add it in runtime..so every user has it already setup in their machine when running my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `src` directory isn't in the python module search path if you run it from the `main` directory. You'll need to either run the script from the `src` directory (a wrapper script, or move it) or add the `src` directory to `sys.path`. This is probably what you want. Here's how:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

(If you're compiling/freezing it with py2exe/py2app/cxfreeze/whatever, you'll need a slightly different solution due to the way it works.)

Comment: I got your point but my main.py is in src/main so the above code does not add path to Modules..Would you elaborate on how to add their path when I need to distribute the code ?

Comment: @Arash Sorry, I meant dirname of dirname rather than just dirname. Fixed now.

Comment: If you can have a script in the root of `src` it's easier. And you can even have it just doing `from main import main; main()`, if you like.

Comment: Is there a difference between the code you posted earlier and the edited version?I cant see what has been edited.

Comment: @Arash There is; clicking on the "edited *[some time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7478352/revisions)*" link gets you a way you can see what's changed. I added another level of `os.path.dirname()`-calling.